# eWay issue: Querying by Transaction ID is only available for transactions created via Rapid

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am using Transaction Query to get payment details using transaction ID, but it returns details if the transaction created via Rapid itself, although in eWay documentation this should happen if I am using  invoice number & reference NOT transaction ID

```
$client = \Eway\Rapid::createClient($apiKey, $apiPassword, $apiEndpoint);       
$response = $client->queryTransaction(166593832);
print_r($response);

//result
Eway\Rapid\Model\Response\QueryTransactionResponse Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => Transactions [1] => Errors [2] => Message ) [errors:protected] => Array ( ) [attributes:protected] => Array ( [Transactions] => Array ( ) [Errors] => ) )
```

Comment: To be clear - you want to query the result of a transaction made through an older gateway? Why not use Rapid for the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the documentation isn't correct at the moment - Rapid's Transaction Query can only return transactions created by Rapid (whether querying by invoice reference, ID or Access Code).

If you are using an older gateway, you could try the [query service](https://www.eway.com.au/eway-partner-portal/resources/eway-api/query-service) - you'll need to log in with your eWAY Partner account to view the details.

Comment: just wondering would you have an answer to this question. I am a bit stuck with querying the payments from eway.  Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72098103/null-returned-when-using-eway-transactionquery